# JQuery call a php function on submit issue

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have a form in php and a function that I want to call via jquery once that form is sumbit. Here is my attempt but It doesnt seem to work! does the url have to be the complete url of my page or just my php script name? also do I need to append the function onto the end of that url in order for jquery to call and send that function the submited value from the form?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#search_box").submit(function() {
                    dataform = $("#search").val();

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                             url: "tree2.php",
                             data: dataform,
                             success: function() {
                               alert('success!');
                               $('#search_box').fadeOut(100).hide();


                              }
                           })
            });

    });
</script>
</head>
<?php

    form();
   if($_POST['submit'])
    process();    

function form(){
    echo"<div class='searchbox'>";
    echo "<form method='post' id='search_box' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='search' name='species'/>"; 
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' />"; 
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";

}


function process(){

    $searchvar = htmlentities($_POST['species']);
    echo $searchvar;
 }
```

Comment: There are lots of similar question present in **Related** section.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        // Get all the post parameters
        dataform = { submit: 1,
                     species: $("#search").val()
                   };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "", // Post to the current page
            data: dataform,
            success: function(result) {
                alert('success! ' + result); // Do something with result
                $('#search_box').fadeOut(100).hide();
            }
        });
        return false; // Prevent default submission
    });
});
```

You weren't providing field names in your data, and you didn't supply the `submit` field at all, so `if ($_POST['submit'])` would never be true.

Change the PHP to:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
  process();
} else {
  form();
}
```

This will display the form when the page is loaded normally, but process the AJAX query when the `submit` field is set.

You don't need to supply an absolute URL. A relative URL will be interpreted relative to the directory containing the page performing the AJAX call, just like following a link.

Comment: I think you have to also include `preventDefault();` to prevent explicitly submitting the form.

Comment: do I need to get rid of the php logic? since its already being declared in jquery?

Comment: Is `tree2.php` the script you posted, or some other script?

Comment: yeah its this script, tree2.php

Comment: Then you need the PHP logic to distinguish displaying the page initially and processing the AJAX call. Also, you shouldn't call `form()` when `$_POST['submit']` is true. And your AJAX function isn't doing anything with the value that's returned from the server.

Comment: so basically the function process does a lot more with that value, I just didnt include it because its a lot more php code. how can I get it to basically pass that form value and execute that function with the value normally?

Answer (score 0):

here is your updated code and it is working for me

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {        
        $("#submit").click(function() {             
                    dataform = $("#search").val();
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                             url: "tree2.php",
                             data: dataform,
                             success: function() {
                               alert('success!');
                               $('#search_box').fadeOut(100).hide();
                              }
                           })            
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<?php
    form();
   if($_POST['submit'])
    process();    

function form(){
    echo"<div class='searchbox'>";
    echo "<form method='post' id='search_box' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>";
    echo "<input type='text' id='search' name='species'/>"; 
    echo "<input type='button' name='submit' id='submit' value ='submit'/>"; 
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
}

function process(){
    $searchvar = htmlentities($_POST['species']);
    echo $searchvar;
 }
?>
```

Comment: hi the function process doesnt execute normally, it doesnt receive anything

Comment: it is working on my end and aleart success at the end, use firebug to see ouput

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search_box").submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                         url: "http://www.hostname.com/tree2.php",
                         data: $('#search_box').serialize(),  
                         success: function() {
                           alert('success!');
                           $('#search_box').fadeOut(100).hide();
                          }
                       })
        });
```

You will have to send the data using serialize() and you will be able to receive the data in tree.php server page as normal way. As we receive the POST data from the form. Secondly use the full path to the tree.php. It will work surely.Try.